# Proving that ${4a \choose 2a} - {2a \choose a}$ is divisible by 4

Tags: combinatorics, induction, divisibility

I'm trying to prove that ${4a \choose 2a} - {2a \choose a}$ is divisible by $4$, and I've currently tried using induction, though I have been unsuccessful. I'm not really sure where to go to for now, any help would be appreciated.

**This is what I have currently done;**
For $a=1$ we have that ${4a \choose 2a} - {2a \choose a} = {4 \choose 2} - {2 \choose 1} = 4$, which is divisible by $4$ and hence the statement is true for $a=1$.

Assume true for $a =n$ (where $n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Required to prove true for $a = n+1$. We have that;
$${4(a+1) \choose 2(a+1)} - {2(a+1) \choose a+1} = {4a+4 \choose 2a+2} - {2a+2 \choose a+1} $$
Though
$${2a+2 \choose a+1}  = {2a+1 \choose a} + {2a+1 \choose a+1} = 2 {2a+1 \choose a}$$
However, applying the same binomial identity we get that ${2a+1 \choose a} = {2a \choose a - 1} + {2a \choose a}$. Hence our original expression can be written as;
$${4a+4 \choose 2a+2} - {2a+2 \choose a+1}  = {4a+4 \choose 2a+2} - 2 {2a+1 \choose a} $$

After here I'm not sure where to go?

Comment: Show us your work, even if you got stuck, or got an incorrect answer.  Surely you can show us the basis step, and state the inductive hypothesis?  You've been here for over three years on this site, have over 1k rep, and so I assume you know that this question, as it stands now, is a very low quality PSQ.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: I am going for the overkill. By Legendre's theorem exponent of the largest power of $2$ dividing $n!$ is $\sum_{k\geq 1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor$, hence
$$ \nu_2\binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{2^k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\right)\tag{1}$$
and the LHS is given by the number of "$1$"s in the binary representation of $n$. If we assume that $n$ has $k$ "1"s in its binary representation then both $\binom{2n}{n}$ and $\binom{4n}{2n}$ are numbers of the form $2^k\cdot\text{odd}$, hence their difference is a multiple of $2^{k+1}$. Since $k\geq 1$, we are done.